# How can I use a bool in two scripts to decide if to call a function or not?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the first script in the FixedUpdate() I'm calling this function :

```
private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            RotateView();
        }
```

Inside RotateView :

```
public void RotateView()
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<FPEMouseLook>().LookRotation(transform, m_Camera.transform);
        }
```

And in the second script I'm calling the RotateView like this :

```
Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEPlayer.Instance.GetComponent<Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEFirstPersonController>().RotateView();
```

But now I want to add a bool to the script with the RotateView function so I can decide in the second script if to call or not the RotateView in the FixedUpdate.

I want to control if the RotateView will be called or not in the FixedUpdate from the second script or better to control if the line :

```
gameObject.GetComponent<FPEMouseLook>().LookRotation(transform, m_Camera.transform);
```

Will be executed or not depending on what flag I set in the second script for example :

```
Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEPlayer.Instance.GetComponent<Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEFirstPersonController>().RotateView(false);
```

false so it will not use the line :

```
gameObject.GetComponent<FPEMouseLook>().LookRotation(transform, m_Camera.transform);
```

And true will use it. Or false/true if to call the RotateView from inside the FixedUpdate in the first script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many ways to do it:

- You can assign one script to other via the inspector by using `[SerializeField] OtherScript foo;`
- You can have the bool be public and `static`, then it becomes accessible via `OtherScript.foo`
- You can use one of the many ways to grab the other component in the `Start()` of one of the scripts, e.g. `FindObjectByType()` or `GetComponent<...>()` or `GetComponentInChildren<...>()`, the bool could then be public or public but using a { get; private set; } accessor, or made available via a public function like `GetFoo()`
- For super-rare bool checks, like for initial loading settings, there's also the `PlayerPrefs` class in Unity (but it would usually then be put into another variable)
- You may even find you're going about the shared bool approach wrong, and instead you want to have one class handle the `RotateView` call of the other etc.

It all somewhat depends on how you structure your program, what the classes should do, what their scope is and so on.